# Creating confluence plugin

Tags: rest, plugins, confluence

I am new to confluence. Actually i want to create some kind of plugin or page template or something which will have the below things

1. The page should have a date filter and it will have a getDetails button.
2. on the getDetails click event it should send the request to REST API
3. I have a REST api hosted  It will return some result and I want the result should be shown in the confluence page

Is there any way to do this. Any example or tutorials to start with.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to create a Confluence plugin are too involved to fit into a Stack Overflow answer.

Luckily, there's a great tutorial on the Atlassian web site that closely relates to what you're looking for:

[Creating a Confluence Task Plugin with REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Creating+a+Confluence+Task+Plugin+with+REST)